# Pivot Or Transpose this Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have this Table

[image: Income Table],

I want the data grouped by year, as the following table show

[image: Desired Table]

I tried this codes

```
SELECT * 
FROM    
(
  SELECT Year, Income 
 FROM Sales 
) t 
pivot 
(
   count([Income]) for[Income]in ([1],[2],[3])
) as event_count;
```

However I'm getting Null Values

```
Year  1  2  3
2015  0  0  0
```

What is best way to achieve the desired result? Please forgive me, the way I arranged the question as I'm new in this forum.

Comment: I think the answer here addresses your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255640/mysql-reshape-data-from-long-tall-to-wide

Comment: sub query should be like `SELECT Year, Income, Row_Number() OVER (Partition By Year Order By Income) Rn`  then in your pivot use `MAX([Income]) for [Rn] in ([1],[2],[3])`

Comment: Thank for the answer, however I have solved the question through this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999264/transpose-rows-and-columns-with-no-aggregate